# Context Menu blocks Drag and Drop into new window

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop, ipados, uiscene

This iPadOS/iOS 13 app implements both multiple windows and drag and drop. In almost every case, both work perfectly.

We encounter our only problem in a table view that implements the context menu methods of UITableViewDelegate.

```
- tableView:contextMenuConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:point:Beta
- tableView:willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWithConfiguration:animator:Beta
```

If we initiate the drag *before* the Context Menu appears, then we can successfully drag the item into a new window (UIScene) by moving it to the edge of the screen. However, if we initiate the drag *after* the Context Menu has appeared, it is not possible to drag the item into a new window or scene.

Does anyone know what the source of the problem is?

Here are two contrasting videos showcasing the problem:

**Failure**

[image: This is the drag and drop failing.]

**Success**

[image: This is the drag and drop succeeding.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Identified Problem**

In `viewDidAppear:` we were executing the following:

```
UISceneActivationConditions *conditions = self.view.window.windowScene.activationConditions;
conditions.prefersToActivateForTargetContentIdentifierPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", self.note.noteID];
conditions.canActivateForTargetContentIdentifierPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", self.note.noteID];
```

When a Context Menu was displayed, `viewDidAppear:` was called and the `.activationConditions` were applied to the current UIScene.

Note that the Context Menu's previewing view controller shares the NSUserActivity details with the drag + drop item, and so the `.targetContentIdentifier` of the NSUserActivity we were trying to drag was matching the `.activationConditions` predicate of the current UIScene. Consequently, when displaying the Context Menu's previewing view controller, we were telling the system that the current UIScene is the optimal recipient of the drag event, preventing other, new windows from receiving it (at least, that's my supposition).

(While I disagree with that behavior, it seems to be how UIScene Activation Conditions are being interpreted in this iOS 13.1.3.)

**The Solution**

To fix it I simply prevented the configuration of `.activationConditions` when displaying the view controller within a Context Menu.

Here's an **updated video** showing successful drag + drop, even with the Context Menu being displayed:
[image: Successfully using drag and drop with Context Menu]